# How to find two points along an existing line

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry, points

I'm sure this is basic trigonometry, and I bet I covered at school many years ago, but I struggle knowing what function to apply to a real world situation. Anyway, rather than try and explain what I need help with, I've drawn a little diagram:

[image]

I know p1, p2, r1 and r2 but I can't remember (or know how to search for) how to work out what p3 and p4 are.

The basic application of this setup is I have 2 circles (red and blue) and I need them constantly connected as I drag them around the canvas. The pink link will connect them via their centre points but I don't want the line to penetrate the circle's circumferences.

Hope that makes sense? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: It is not off topic and there is a very good reason why I posted here as opposed to the Maths Exchange board. 

The context is intended for JavaScript implementation. If I had written such a request in Math Exchange I would have gotten answers expressed in equations using math notation. I would not have understood how to implement the answer. By asking it here I would ensure it is expressed in code notation. 

I excluded the information about which language I am using because it is irrelevant.

I think the answers people left will be useful to others who face this maths issue in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simple vector math (no trigonometry needed)

1. **create unit vector `v` with `P1` to `P2` direction**

   That is easy in vector form:

   ```
   v=P2-P1; v/=|v|
   ```

   And when put into **2D**:

   ```
   v.x=P2.x-P1.x;
   v.y=P2.y-P1.y;
   l=sqrt((v.x*v.x)+(v.y*v.y))
   v.x/=l;
   v.y/=l;
   ```
2. **Now just translate from `P1,P2`by `r1,r2`**

   Vector form:

   ```
   P3=P1+r1*v
   P4=P2-r2*v
   ```

   In **2D**:

   ```
   P3.x=P1.x+r1*v.x;
   P3.y=P1.y+r1*v.y;
   P4.x=P2.x-r2*v.x;
   P4.y=P2.y-r2*v.y;
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time (and effort with your diagram). I have selected your answer as I work better in vector match and I am using a vector-based system for my drawing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve the following equation system:

For p3 -->

```
(X-p1x)/(p1x-p2x)=(Y-p1y)/(p1y-p2y)
(X-p1x)^2 + (Y-p1y)^2 = r1^2
```

The same for p4 just change r1 for r2 and p1 for p4 in the second equation.

The first equation is the equation of a line given 2 points.
And the second equation is the equation of a circle given a center point and a radius.

The resulting X, Y values will be the values of p3, and then p4.

Answer (score 1):

What I am going to say is a little long. I will let you write your own code, however, of course will not help with that.

You know points P1, P2, and radius R1 and R2. Say suppose points P1 and P2 have coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) respectively.

The line connecting P1 and P2 is a straight line and hence you can calculate the slope of the line using the formula `m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`. Since you know the slope and know two coordinates, you can calculate the intercept `c` and construct a formula of the form `y=mx+c`.

Once the line formula is there, you can apply values for x and calculate y for point P3, lets say x3 and y3 since you have the radius R1. Similarly, calculate the coordinates for P4.

Comment: Thank you for your time, could you clarify what 'c' is in the second part of the formula: 'y=mx+c'? Thanks.

Comment: @jayfield1979 it is the line `y` position when `x=0` (line offset) from the standard line equation. This approach will no work for vertical lines and will lose accuracy for cases where `|dy|>>|dx|`. Vector and or parametric approach is better for this

Answer (score 1):

Let d be the distance between p1(x1, y1) and p2(x2,y2)
Thus 
d = sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)
Now point p3(x3, y3) divides the line between p1 and p2 in the ratio of r1:(d-r1)

Thus
x3 = (r1*x2 + (d-r1)*x1)/d and
y3 = (r1*y2 + (d-r1)*y1)/d

Similarly for p4(x4, y4)
x4 = (r2*x1 + (d-r2)*x2)/d and
y4 = (r2*y1 + (d-r2)*y2)/d